# Sort list with empty and null values at the end

Tags: java, java-stream

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private String position;

    // constructor, getters, setters

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Test> footballTeam = new ArrayList<>();
        Test player1 = new Test("John", "Forward");
        Test player2 = new Test("John", "OT");
        Test player3 = new Test("Sam", "Center ");
        Test player4 = new Test("John", null);
        Test player5 = new Test("Adam", "Opener");
        Test player6 = new Test("Nik", "QB");
        Test player7 = new Test("John", "");

        footballTeam.add(player1);
        footballTeam.add(player2);
        footballTeam.add(player3);
        footballTeam.add(player4);
        footballTeam.add(player5);
        footballTeam.add(player6);
        footballTeam.add(player7);

        footballTeam.sort(Comparator.comparing(Test::getName)
            .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Test::getPosition, 
                   Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));

        footballTeam.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I have this data I am trying to sort this list by Name first and then by position.  This is the output I get

```
Adam Opener    
John  
John Forward  
John OT  
John null  
Nik QB  
Sam Center
```

I want all the `null` and `""` for a particular player to be at the end of the list. Note that the order of `null` vs `""` is not that important.

Expected Outcome

```
Adam Opener  
John Forward  
John OT  
John   
John null  
Nik QB  
Sam Center
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order between `null` and empty string is not significant, then you could declare a function, that would return `null` if the `position` is an empty string. Then use this instead of `Test::getPosition`

```java
Function<Test, String> getPosition = t -> {
    String pos = t.getPosition();
    return (pos != null && pos.isEmpty()) ? null : pos;
};

footballTeam.sort(Comparator.comparing(Test::getName)
            .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(getPosition, 
                   Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));
```